# jquery Single image slider

Tags: jquery, html

I need to build a single image slider. There is an example an image slider downstairs but it is not working property. When I press left button the slider work ok but when I click right button it goes out of scope.

HTML:

```
<div class="slider">
    <img src="http://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-k__maLyJIPw/UWV1-WyW9rI/AAAAAAAAAJk/MVfNsKPQLsU/s1539/slider.png" alt="" />
    <a href="" class="left">left</a>
    <a href="" class="right">right</a>
</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var SELIDER_OFFSET_LEFT = $(".slider").offset().left;
    $(".slider .left,.slider .right").click(function(){
        var lambda = -1;
        var isLeft = false;   
        var animateWidth = 100;
        var isFirst = true;
        if($(this).hasClass('left')){
            lambda = 1;
            isLeft = true;
        }

        var leftOfImg =   $(".slider img").offset().left;
        console.log(leftOfImg); 
         console.log('*');
        console.log(SELIDER_OFFSET_LEFT);

       var leftTTT = (isFirst)?SELIDER_OFFSET_LEFT - animateWidth:SELIDER_OFFSET_LEFT;
        if(leftOfImg  >= leftTTT &&  isLeft){
             return false;
        }else if(leftOfImg + $(".slider img").width() && !isLeft){

        }   

        var isFirst = false;

        $(".slider img").stop().animate({
            marginLeft: '-='+-animateWidth*lambda
        },1000);
        return false;
    });

});
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/5AdTe/1/

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

3 things I can see are wrong, all in the else block at line 21

```
else if(leftOfImg + $(".slider img").width() && !isLeft)
```

1) You need a logical operator here '< / > / ==' not a '+'

2) the leftOfImg variable is getting smaller when you animate right

3) there is no return statement in the else block even if it does fire so it will just keep animating